# Como leer y sobrescribir una serie de documentos(.txt) en c#

Tags: c#, base-de-datos

Estoy teniendo dudas acerca de este método ya que si lo leo de forma (foreach) teniendo en cuenta el formato del documento, aun no sabría como buscar el documento especifico si lo desease.

También quisiera tener en cuenta si un documento que esta repetido(si se crea uno nuevo) poder escribir dentro de este.

```
string path = @"E:\Documentos\Ejemplo.txt";
if (!File.Exists(path))
{
       File.Create(path);
       TextWriter tw = new StreamWriter(path);
       tw.WriteLine("The very first line!");
       tw.Close();
}
else if (File.Exists(path))
{
       TextWriter tw = new StreamWriter(path);
       tw.WriteLine("The next line!");
       tw.Close(); 
}
```

Por otra parte si se pudiera quisiera poder modificarlo en el mismo lo busco, es decir una consulta tipo base de datos.

En donde podría empezar a investigar o a tener idea atenué a lo que se usa hoy en estas bases en función a la documentación en una base de datos local.

Comment: Hola,podrías agregar más detalle a tu duda? Lo que muestras como código es un ejemplo de lectura y escritura. Puedes exponer el código fuente que has generado hasta el momento y los errores que estas presentando? O quizás el objetivo que persigues para poder guiarte de la mejor manera, ya que lo que describes se ve muy ambiguo. Saludos.

Answer (score 0):

Buscar archivos en un directorio

```
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            System.IO.DirectoryInfo dinfo = new System.IO.DirectoryInfo(@"c:\folder");
            //recorrer los archivos en el directorio
            foreach (System.IO.FileInfo finfo in dinfo.GetFiles())
            {
                System.IO.StreamReader reader = new System.IO.StreamReader(finfo.FullName);
                while (!reader.EndOfStream)
                {
                    string curLine = reader.ReadLine();
                }
                reader.Close();
            }
        }
```

Para escribir utiliza el StreamWriter es muy práctico

```
        //crea dos objetos writer
        System.IO.StreamWriter writer_overwrite = new System.IO.StreamWriter("Archivo.txt");
        System.IO.StreamWriter writer = new System.IO.StreamWriter("Archivo2.txt");

        //escdribe en ambos archivos
        writer_overwrite.WriteLine("linea 1");
        writer.WriteLine("linea a");

        //cierro ambos archivos

        writer_overwrite.Close();
        writer.Close();

        //coloca una pausa para que vayas a revisar los archivos y espera un enter
        Console.WriteLine("Revisa los archivos, enter para continuar");
        Console.ReadLine();


        //vuelvo a hacer todo con objetos distintos abriendo los mismos archivos
        //archivo.txt se sobre escribirá, archivo2.txt agregará el texto
        System.IO.StreamWriter writer_overwrite_2 = new System.IO.StreamWriter("Archivo.txt");
        //el segundo archivo lo abro para agregar, el segundo parámetro es append = true
        System.IO.StreamWriter writer_2 = new System.IO.StreamWriter("Archivo2.txt", true);

        writer_overwrite_2.WriteLine("linea 2");
        writer_2.WriteLine("linea b");


        writer_overwrite_2.Close();
        writer_2.Close();
```

Para bases de datos es mejor usar archivos de base de datos como access o un servidor sqlexpress, sistemas de archivo plano muy complicado ahora que ya hay otros medios

Answer (score 0):

using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;

namespace WsConsultaExamen.Controllers
{    [ApiController]
public class ConsultaController : ControllerBase
{
private static string pathBase = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory;

```
    [NonAction]
    public List<string> ReaderCsvFile()
    {
        List<string> listA = new List<string>();
        int i = 0;
        using (var reader = new StreamReader(@$"{pathBase}\archivoCsv\CLIENTES.csv"))
        {
            while (!reader.EndOfStream)
            {
                var line = reader.ReadLine();
                listA.Add(line);

            }
        }
        return listA;
    }
    [HttpGet("{Registros}")]
    public IActionResult Consulta(int Registros)
    {
        ConsultaModel consultaModel = new ConsultaModel();
        List<ConsultaModel> response = new();
        List<string> dataList = new List<string>();
        dataList  = ReaderCsvFile();
        for (int j = 1; j <= Registros; j++)
        {
            var values = dataList[j].Trim().Split(';');
            response.Add(new ConsultaModel
            {
  C40FUM = values[0].Trim(),
  C40NID = values[1].Trim(),
  C40TID = values[2].Trim(),
  C40DIG = values[3].Trim(),
  C40NIP = values[4].Trim(),
  C40FCC = values[5].Trim(),
  C40NOM = values[6].Trim(),
  C40TNO = values[7].Trim(),
  C40GRF = values[8].Trim(),
  C40FIN = values[9].Trim(),
  C40LNE = values[10].Trim(),
  C40FPI = values[11].Trim(),
  C40TRF = values[12].Trim(),
  C40GER = values[13].Trim(),
  C40AUC = values[14].Trim(),
  C40CLP = values[15].Trim(),
  C40SUC = values[16].Trim(),
  C40EST = values[17].Trim(),
  C40IEB = values[18].Trim(),
  C40IEC = values[19].Trim(),
  C40IVC = values[20].Trim(),
  C40IVT = values[21].Trim(),
  C40IVA = values[22].Trim(),
  C40USR = values[23].Trim(),
  C40FUA = values[24].Trim(),
  C40HUA = values[25].Trim(),
  C40NO1 = values[26].Trim(),
  C40NO2 = values[27].Trim(),
  C40AP1 = values[28].Trim(),
  C40AP2 = values[29].Trim()
            }
            );
        }
        return Ok(response);
    }

}
```

}

Comment: Pulsa en [edit] y explica brevemente el funcionamiento del código, además de corregir su formato y explicar _cómo responde esto a la pregunta_. Recuerda que [es.so] no es un repositorio de código. De nuevo, lee [answer] y haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio.